# Helper function: How to disable forbidden words?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've been tasked to add a filtering function for forbidden usernames.
I've created a huge list of these names and split everything into two parts, one containing a list of exact matches, the other with a phrase/word match list.

The exact match works as intended (e.g. "admin", "adminello" - is allowed), but the phrase/word match only works in a way if that word is found within a sentence, e.g. "sh*t hello". I should also make it work dashes, "sh*t-hello" and even combined string like "sh*thsh*thellosh*t".

Should I also divide the list, because atm it's one JSON file like:

```
{
"admin": 1,
"sh*t": 2
}
```

Helper function
(badNamesList - JSON file)

```
 module.exports = (options = {}) => {
  return async context => {
    const argumentsList = _.get(context, 'arguments', []);
    const username = _.size(argumentsList) > 1 ? _.get(argumentsList[1], 'username') : null;
    if (username) {
      const exactMatchList = _.map(badNamesList, (name, key) => {
        if (name === 1) return key;
      });
      const phraseMatchList = _.map(badNamesList, (name, key) => {
        if (name === 2) return key;
      });
      if (_.includes(exactMatchList, _.toLower(username))) {
        throw new errors.BadRequest({ fieldErrors: { username: 'forbiddenUsername' } });
      }
      if (_.some(phraseMatchList, name => _.includes(_.map(_.split(username, /-| /), _.toLower), name))) {
        throw new errors.BadRequest({ fieldErrors: { username: 'forbiddenUsername' } });
      }
    }
    return context;
  };
};
```

Comment: Checkout my answer on this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56491415/2784493 - this might help you.

Comment: While it's a nice list of forbidden names, it still allows things like 'shltshlt' or 'dlckshlt', etc. Adding those in manually is a waste of time

Comment: well at least you don't have to think of the other stuff like `assH0le`(with a zero) and other common bad words, unless you want to manually add ALL of them on your list, which I think is a more waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas how to do this properly?

You could use the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm.

So you can:

- transform the `username` to lowercase, changing numbers to letter (eg: `0=o`) and remove duplicated string (eg: `shitshit`)
- find the distance of the username with a list of banned words
- if the distance equals or too much near, block it

In this case, you could have false-positive like:
`shot` that has distance 1 to `shit` but you don't need to create an "up to infinity" dictionary